# How to read a specific exported const from a TypeScript file inside a Vite Plugin?

Tags: typescript, vite, zod

I'm developing a Vite Plugin. I want to read certain TypeScript files and a specific exported const `schema` of them. I don't know how to do that.

I've tried to use the file watcher and import the file:

```
const zodToJsonSchema = ({ input, output = "dist" }: zodToJsonSchemaOptions): PluginOption => {
  return {
    name: "vite-plugin-zod-to-json-schema",
    async configureServer(server) {
      const { watcher } = server;

      watcher.add(input);

      watcher.on("change", async (path) => {
        if (path.endsWith("features.ts")) {
          const importedFile = await import(path);
        }
      });
    },
  };
};
```

Unfortunately I cannot dynamically import a Typescript file, because Vite seems not to know Typescript, even though the vite.config.ts itself is a Typescript file.

I expected that I can access `importedFile.schema` to access the exported const I want to process or pass along. How to do this?

Comment: You probably have to parse the source to create an AST and go from there. https://astexplorer.net/

Comment: @morganney I see. Doesn't vite have already an AST of this file? How can I get the instance of the exported schema from the AST?

Comment: They might have the AST, in fact they probably do if you use the right hook. You have to walk the AST to inspect the node types and get what you're after. Use the website I linked you to for some help.

Comment: That seems to be quite a hard task. Create ASTs for the typescript files, extract exported `schema`s from the AST, create new functions which pass the extracted exported `schema` to another function, setting up the right context for the typescript vm, execution of the functions, receiving the results and writing json files. Seems to be a very hard task to do with this stack. :(
I think I going to abandon the idea. Thank you @morganney for your help.

Comment: It's actually quite fun once you get started. Glad I could help either way.